# Using 20, 17, 16, 8, 7 to make 9

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-property

You can use $+, -, \times, $ or $/$ (namely $\div$).

Use all five numbers (20, 17, 16, 8, and 7) only once to make $9$.

From what I've been told there are $4$ answers.  The only one I've been able to figure out is:

> $$\Bigg((17-7)\times\left(\frac{20}{8}\right)\Bigg)-16=9$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the given numbers supposed to be used only  once ?

Comment: is concatenation allowed?

Comment: You can only use them once.  I don't know what concatenation is but I would assume no.  I was told addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

Comment: Nice.  I've been working on this thing for weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one:

> $$\Bigg((20-7)\times\left(\frac{16}{8}\right)\Bigg)-17=9$$

Answer (score 4):

Here are four answers:

1. > $20\times\frac{17-7}{8}-16$
2. > $\frac{20\times(16-8)-7}{17}$
3. > $(20-7)\times\frac{16}{8}-17$
4. > $167+20-178$

Comment: $1$ and $3$ are the same equation

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid fixed it.

Comment: not sure if concatenation is allowed, asked the OP, didn't get an answer yet.

Comment: Concatenation is not allowed.

Comment: @NateSmith these are only solutions, I did it with computer, checked all solutions. so if concatenation is not allowed, there are 3 answers.